# Get the authentication method of a SQL Report Service

Tags: authentication, reporting-services

Is it possible to get the authentication method of a SQL Report Service? I have an application to deploy RDLs (found [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rhundhausen/archive/2006/12/26/deploy-rdl-files-to-multiple-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-servers.aspx) by the way). It has the following code (simplified):

```
ReportingService2005 ws = new ReportingService2005();
ws.Url = url;
ws.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ws.CreateReport(....)
// and so on
```

But what if a server needs a username and password? As this piece of code will be used on multiple servers, I would need a method to request the authentication method first. If its integrated security, I could use the code above. If not, I could ask the user a username and password.

I've tried with `ws.GetSystemProperties` to request the `EnableIntegratedSecurity` property, but I still get an exception (407 Proxy Authentication Required). I could catch the exception and then prompt for username and password, but prefer not to use this exception-driven style.

Comment: What's the harm in the exception style? Cache the auth method for that server url and it will only happen once.

Comment: True, but if there is a way to just request it, that would be nice. I've always learnt that logic using exceptions is bad, which I agree with. If there's no other way, I will use it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as noone is answering this anymore, and probably never will, I'm going to assume I'll have to use the exception-way:

If the above code doesn't work, catch the exception and request a username and password. Then call CreateReport with those credentials. If there's another exception, handle it gracefully...